# mvc3 clickable link into plaintext

Tags: hyperlink, plaintext

is there a way to get the my website in plaintext or in some form to show the tag and the content inside? so that some can copy the whole thing..

I have tried

```
<plaintext>
<a href="mysite">my website</a>




</plaintext>
```

but the plaintext messes up all the other tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing each `<` with `&lt;`  and each `>` with `&gt;`, so that

```
<a href="mysite">my website</a>
```

becomes

```
&lt;a href="mysite"&gt;my website&lt;/a&gt;
```

and renders in the browser as

`<a href="mysite">my website</a>`

instead of

> my website